# UITableView - sectionIndexColor for the selected index

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, ios8

I am able to change the color of the section indices by using sectionIndexColor property of UITableView and now, I would like to highlight the Index which is selected by setting a different color.

If I use sectionIndexColor property again, then this results in changing color of all the section indices.

I don't want to use any 3rd party library here so let me know if there is any API available with iOS 8.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look through the documentation for `UITableView` and it does not appear as though there are any public APIs available to help achieve what you're trying to do. Furthermore, `UITableView` doesn't even expose a `sectionIndex` property so there's really no great way of even looping through its subviews (which would likely get you rejected from the app store anyway). I think your only option is to build a custom `sectionIndex` (by subclassing `UIView`) if you need to modify yours further than the text color or background color.

Here's one example (though I haven't tried it myself):
https://github.com/gdavis/GDIIndexBar

Comment: Thanks Brian for this quick reply. I did check your suggested example but, unfortunately, I did not find a way to highlight the selected index and looks like subclassing is the only option left out :| keep me updated if you could find a way to achieve this. Thanks again.